# WebForm_PostBackOptions use actionUrl with ampersand

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web, webforms

I use a overridden LinkButton and get this HTML-element

```
<a id="ucSearchForm_lbSearch" tabindex="3" class="button" rel="nofollow" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ucSearchForm$lbSearch", "", false, "", "http://localhost:81/main-jobs/rgn-Islamabad-+-FCA-%26-AJK", false, true))'><p>Find</p></a>
```

WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions and WebForm_PostBackOptions is standart asp.net webform js function and I don't have access to them.

When I click on the link, WebForm_PostBackOptions receives not the correct link(`http://localhost:81/main-jobs/rgn-Islamabad-+-FCA-&-AJK` - automatically decoded ampersand) and I do not get postBack.
If i use web console and run the code itself, then everything is working correctly. I get link `http://localhost:81/main-jobs/rgn-Islamabad-+-FCA-%26-AJK`.

Is it possible to solve this problem, or should look for a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a double-encoded `("http://localhost:81/main-jobs/rgn-Islamabad-+-FCA-%2526-AJK")` and it worked.